# if next(item) moves to the next item in a list, what is the eqvilant of next next(item) python

Tags: python, file, iterator

heres the code for context.

```
    def processScores( file, score):
#opens file using with method, reads each line with a for loop. If content in line
#agrees with parameters in  elif statements, executes code in if statment. Otherwise, ignores line    

    with open(file,'r') as f:
        for line in f:  #starts for loop for all if statements
            line = line.strip()
            if line.isdigit():
                start = int(line)
                score.initialScore(start)
                print(line)#DEBUG TEST**** #checks if first line is a number if it is adds it to intial score

            elif len(line) == 0:
                print(line)#DEBUG TEST****
                continue        #if a line has nothing in it. skip it  

            elif line == 'o' or line == 'O':
                amount = next(f)
                print(line)#DEBUG TEST****
                score.updateOne(amount) #if line contains single score marker, Takes content in next line and
                                        #inserts it into updateOne
            elif line == 'm'or line == 'M':
                scoreList = next(f)
                lst = []
                for item in scoreList:
                    print(line)#DEBUG TEST****
                    lst.append(item)
                    score.updateMany(lst) # if line contains list score marker, creates scoreList variable and places the next line into  that variable
                                          # creates lst variable and sets it to an empty list
                                          # goes through the next line with the for loop and appends each item in the next line to the empty list
                                          # then inserts newly populated lst into updateMany

            elif line == 'X':
                print(line)#DEBUG TEST****
                score.get(self)
                score.average(self) # if line contains terminator marker. prints total score and the average of the scores.
                                    # because the file was opened with the 'with' method. the file closes after
```

the idea that I am trying to is work with  a file that looks like this:

50

O

30

O

40

M

10 20 30

o

5

m

1 2 3

X

if the code sees an 'O' or an 'o' then it needs to take the next line in the code and add it to a running score.. However the next line is a blank space... So I need to skip to the second line after the 'O' or 'o'.

I was thinking of doing an exception for this, but before I go down that road I  wanna see if anyone might know of a better way.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to move along `f` skipping whitespace-only items,

```
while True:
    x = next(f).strip()
    if x: break
```

will work, as will

```
for x in f:
    x = x.strip()
    if x: break
```

The difference is, what if there is **no** following non-all-space item in `f`.  The former will exit with a `StopIteration` exception, the latter exit the `for` loop with no exception but `x` set to `''`.  Pick your poison (which exit form would you rather deal with) and code accordingly!

Answer (score 0):

How about something like:

```
For line in lines:
  if type(line) == 'int':
     oneCount += line
  elif type(line) == 'list':
     manyCount.append(line)
  elif type(line) == 'str' and line != 'x':
     continue
  elif type(line) == None:
     continue
  else:
     print scores
```

Answer (score 0):

A useful model to think about this problem is a state machine.

The code has 3 states:

1. Read command code.
2. Add single score (on "O").
3. Add multiple scores (on "M").

By keeping a variable with the current state, you can process the input without skipping ahead.

Now, empty lines appear to serve no purpose so you could just remove them all from the input like this:

```
...
non_empty_lines = (line for line in f if line.strip())
for line in non_empty_lines:
  ... do your thing ...
```

The generator expression will filter lines that are all spaces.

If for some reason you cannot use generator expressions, then do it inside the loop:

```
...
for line in f:
  if not line.strip():
    continue
  ...
```